# git push user shown in remote property is not me

Tags: git, github

i commit some changes in my local git repertory and then push them to my remote git repertory . the problem is that the push account(or push user) shown in remote repertory is not my account but others, i have set the username and email in my local git repertory, and the commit account (or commit user) shown in remote repertory is also right. Why is there such a problem? What should I do ?

Comment: How exactly are you displaying the commit on the remote side?

Comment: Can you include the commit message in the question? Or show a screenshot of the commit both locally and in the repo?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you use? SSH key or HTTP login/password?

Answer (score 0):

If the repote repo manager (like atlassian stash) knows user accounts and multiple accounts are set up for the same email address, the web interface may associate the 'wrong' account with your email address and display the wrong user for the commit.